# Project Euler 16 - Help in solving it

Tags: go

I'm solving [Project Euler problem 16](http://projecteuler.net/problem=16), I've ended up with a code that can logically solve it, but is unable to process as I believe its overflowing or something? I tried int64 in place of int but it just prints 0,0. If i change the power to anything below 30 it works, but above 30 it does not work, Can anyone point out my mistake? I believe its not able to calculate 2^1000.

```
// PE_16 project main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func power(x, y int) int {
    var pow int
    var final int
    final = 1
    for pow = 1; pow <= y; pow++ {
        final = final * x
    }
    return final
}

func main() {
    var stp int
    var sumfdigits int
    var u, t, h, th, tth, l int
    stp = power(2,1000)
    fmt.Println(stp)
    u = stp / 1 % 10
    t = stp / 10 % 10
    h = stp / 100 % 10
    th = stp / 1000 % 10
    tth = stp / 10000 % 10
    l = stp / 100000 % 10
    sumfdigits = u + t + h + th + tth + l
    fmt.Println(sumfdigits)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach to this problem requires exact integer math up to 1000 bits in size. But you're using `int` which is 32 or 64 bits. [math/big.Int](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) can handle such task. I intentionally do not provide a ready made solution using `big.Int` as I assume your goal is to learn by doing it by yourself, which I believe is the intent of Project Euler.

Comment: Thanks! That should do, but when I declare all of them as big.Int I get error while dividing it by any other integer like 1,10,100,1000,etc .. How would one solve this issue?

Comment: @Rohanchrome: Check if you use correctly http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Div . Do you plan to divide by magnitude constants, explicitly one by one in code up to 10^300? ;-)

Comment: Yeah that would be a bad idea, Didn't think about that :P Should probably write up a proper function. I'll try that and let you know..

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @jnml, `int`s aren't large enough; if you wish to calculate 2^1000 in Go, `big.Int`s are a good choice here.  Note that `math/big` provides the [Exp()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Exp) method which will be easier to use than converting your `power` function to `big.Int`s.

I worked through some Project Euler problems about a year ago, doing them in Go to get to know the language.  I didn't like the ones that required `big.Int`s, which aren't so easy to work with in Go.  For this one, I "cheated" and did it in one line of Ruby:

*Removed because I remembered it was considered bad form to show a working solution, even in a different language.*

Anyway, my Ruby example shows another thing I learned with Go's `big.Int`s: sometimes it's easier to [convert them to a string](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.String) and work with that string than to work with the `big.Int` itself.  This problem strikes me as one of those cases.

Converting my Ruby algorithm to Go, I only work with `big.Int`s on one line, then it's easy to work with the string and get the answer in just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `math/big`.  Below is a school boy maths way of doubling a decimal number as a hint!

`xs` holds the decimal digits in least significant first order. Pass in a pointer to the digits (`pxs`) as the slice might need to get bigger.

```
func double(pxs *[]int) {
    xs := *pxs
    carry := 0
    for i, x := range xs {
        n := x*2 + carry
        if n >= 10 {
            carry = 1
            n -= 10
        } else {
            carry = 0
        }
        xs[i] = n
    }
    if carry != 0 {
        *pxs = append(xs, carry)
    }
}
```